# Python removing stopwords (pandas dataframe) : output same as input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stop-words

Quite new new python and coding, been going well but hit a wall trying to remove stopwords from my dataframe despite it being a seemingly easy task. So perhaps an easy question.

Code is below but I've tried lots of variants based on Youtube and Stackoverflow recommendations.
When I run the code I get no error, everything runs, but my output 'token_text_nostop' is exactly the same as as the input 'token_text'.

Data 'token_text' was **scraped** from a website, tokenized, no caps, no nums, no punctuation, german accents, etc... like this:['vibrierende', 'körperöffnungen', 'rückgriff'...

Remove stop_word function seems to work (tested it on simple text).
So my guess is that either I am not iterating properly over the dataframe, passing it the wrong data(type), or the encoding (or German) is not allowing it to work properly, as I've seen tutorials that look near identical to this and work perfectly.

Thanks in advance for any tips! Happy to provide more info if needed.

```
df = pd.read_csv('TAZ_tokens.csv', header=0, encoding = 'utf-8', dtype={'text':str})

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('german'))

def remove_stopwords(txt):
    txt_nostop = ''.join([w for w in txt if w not in stop_words])
    return txt_nostop

df['token_text_nostop'] = df['token_text'].apply(lambda x: remove_stopwords(x))
```

Comment: In your list comprehension you are iterating through each letter in the token, not each word. Try replacing it with ```[w for w in txt.split() if w not in stop_words]```

Comment: Note that stopwords are all lower case. So you might want to do this as well:
`txt_nostop = ''.join([w for w in txt if w.lower() not in stop_words])`

Comment: Thanks. Tried these but no change. @eva-vw : that was one of my suspicions so hopefully your confirmation slowly moves me in the right direction! Will keep researching and trying!

Comment: If you add some code to re-create a sample of your dataframe we could help check to see if its a type problem or some other issue with how your tokens are stored.

Comment: Hello, what happens if you apply `remove_stopwords` to one element of `df['token_text']` that you know for a fact contains a stop_word ?

Exemple : if `df.loc[42, 'token_text']`  =  `['der', 'die' , 'das', 'auto']`

Then you should have `remove_text(df.loc[42, 'token_text']) == ['auto']`

Comment: @LuisBlanche Same problem: e.g. `remove_stopwords(df.loc[2, 'token_text'])` returns ['eine', 'ahnung', 'von', 'unendlichkeit', 'die',... which has several stopwords right there.

Comment: @eva-vw will look into it but I may be slow on it!

Comment: And if you do `remove_stopwords(['eine', 'ahnung', 'von', 'unendlichkeit', 'die'])`  manually , then it works ? 
If yes, this means there is a problem with your 'token_text' column (it could indeed be encoding). I hope you are using python 3  ?

Comment: @LuisBlanche correct, doing it manually either as you did, or creating a variable, does work.

Comment: @LuisBlanche sorry, not used to the "enter" sends feature... yes using Python 3. Interestingly, also if I create a new csv from scratch, just typing in some sample words manually, I have the same problem as with my orginal df.

Comment: Can you do `type(df.loc[2, 'token_text'])` and verify that you get a list type ?

Comment: @LuisBlanche No! Interesting. It comes back as a str.

Comment: @LuisBlanche Thanks for heading me in the right direction! Imported ast (ast.literal_eval) and looks like it solved the issue! Researching now to find the origin of the problem so it does not happen again.

Answer (score 0):

The discussion revealed my list had gotten changed to a string.
Solution was to import ast and convert it back to a list.
Thanks to those who helps... learned some good general lessons too.

Final code looked like this, more or less:

````
df = pd.read_csv('TAZ_tokens.csv', header=0, encoding = 'utf-8')

import ast
df['tokenized_text'] = df.tokenized_text.apply(lambda s: list(ast.literal_eval(s)))

#Just to confirm change worked
type(df.loc[2, 'token_text']) 

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('german'))

def remove_stopwords(txt):
    txt_nostop = ''.join([w for w in txt if w not in stop_words])
    return txt_nostop

df['token_text_nostop'] = df['token_text'].apply(lambda x: remove_stopwords(x))```
````